# csv in excel and numbers not working correct

Tags: excel, csv, numbers

I have a list in 3 columns.
In order to upload to my mailing list I need to convert in cdv.
NO PROBLEM - BUT
Once converted everything is in one column only seperated by commas.

have been through all forums in the last three days.
Can this be a language set up on my computer.
because it works on other computers.

Comment: Can we see a sample of this csv file?

Answer (score 0):

CSV means "Comma separated values", and really combines three columns into one row, separated only by commas. The text will be perfectly readable for spreadsheet applications, but for humans understanding may be more difficult..

If you want to get formatted text, copy-paste it to Notepad and save the text file. It's also possible to File-SaveAs text, but direct copy is quicker IMHO, as one can detect possible faults quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The list separator is defined in the regional settings of your computer (Region and Language \ Formats \ Additional Settings in WIndows). For US computers, it's generally the comma, for European, the semi-column. Most European computers will save and open csv with semi-columns. Similarly, most US computers will save and open csv with commas. If you try and switch, Excel will not recognize the separator automatically.

You can force the conversion using Data \ Text to columns, or you can change your computer's regional settings and you shouldn't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and discovered that the text encoding mattered. Excel would only recognise my CSV file as a valid CSV file if it was UTF-8 encoded. After that the text appeared in nice columns as expected.

I was creating the CSV file programmatically so I had control over the encoding of the CSV produced, I hope you are as lucky.